# How to execute a Golang template when "{" or "}" are in the static part of the template?

Tags: go, latex, go-templates

My Problem is that, I want to build a letter generator, which first builds a latex-file from user input, and then compiles this via latex to PDF.

The template contains multiple lines like this:

```
\setkomavar{signature}{{{.Name}}}
```

The `latex` part is `\setkomavar{signature}{}`, and the `template` part from go is `{{.Name}}`.

When I try to load the template, it throws this error:

panic: template: letter.tmpl:72: unexpected "}" in command

Is there a trick to help the parser handling such a situation?

Thanks in advance,

Tino

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [Template.Delims](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Delims) to set the delimiters to some non conflicting text. `{{` and `}}` are just the default values, this method allows to select other delimiters.

Alternative method: In you template, where you want latex's `{` and `}`, you can insert some safe text instead, like say `#(` and `)#` and then make a "global" replacement on the *output* from the template. Yet setting delimiters is far easier IMO and quite probably more performant, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is actually to just use the built in whitespace operators, like:

```
\setkomavar{signature}{ {{- .Name -}} }
```

The `-` at the beginning and end will remove whitespace between that token and the next non-template token.

Hope that helps, see [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Text_and_spaces) for more detail

Comment: made my day! was working with a system where I can't change the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I was previously doing this by creating the template function:

```golang
func texArg(s interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("{%v}", s)
}
```

which I registered as `arg` using [template.Funcs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Delims). Then in my template I had:

```golang
\textbf{{.Name | arg}}
```

I think @zzzz's answer above is better as this falls apart when you need to nest it, but I thought I'd leave this here for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

my adhok solution was:

```
\barcode{{print "{" .Barcode}}}
```